# Save request parameters from php to text file

Tags: php, request

I want to save the requested parameters in below code to a simple .txt file i tried other code also but was out of luck.

Can anyone help me on this

```
<?php 
if( isset($_REQUEST['accessFrom']) && $_REQUEST['accessFrom'] != "" &&     $_REQUEST['accessFrom'] == "customer_service")
{
        $eb->userType = 'LOGIN';
        $eb->userCode = $_REQUEST['Mecode'];
        $eb->loginCode = $_REQUEST['Mecode'];
        $eb->loginType = 'CS';
        $eb->userIP = getFinRemoteIP();
}
?>
```

The code i used for printing the requested parameters are as follows.

```
<?php
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to save data from $_REQUEST or from $eb?

Comment: I assume your request.txt file is writable.

Comment: @bugscoder yes it is writable.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
file_put_contents('request.txt', print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```

Comment: the file is still blank, no data printed.

Comment: @BrijeshSavaliya The file is completely blank?  It should print out Array
() if the $_REQUEST is empty